# influxdb_client.InfluxDBClient: OSError: [Errno 113] No route to host Raspberry

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, influxdb

I have written a software that is supposed to cyclically write sensor data into an InfluxDB. I can run the software on my computer (Windows) and on a virtual machine (Ubuntu), and it works fine.

I use
`Python 3.9.2 and InfluxDB 5.3.1 on myPI Python 3.10.12 and InfluxDB 5.3.1 on myVM Python 3.1.6 and InfluxDB 5.3.1 on Win PC`

CODE:

```
def write_to_cloud_influxdb(data_points):`
    try:
        client = influxdb_client.InfluxDBClient(url=CLOUD_INFLUXDB_HOST, token=CLOUD_INFLUXDB_TOKEN, org=CLOUD_INFLUXDB_ORG)
        client = client.write_api(write_options=SYNCHRONOUS)
        client.write(record=data_points, org=f"{CLOUD_INFLUXDB_ORG}", bucket=CLOUD_INFLUXDB_DATABASE)        
        print("Data written to Cloud InfluxDB.")
    except ApiException as e:
        print(f"Error writing data to Cloud InfluxDB: {str(e)}")
    finally:
        client.close()
```

Now, I want to run the whole thing on a Raspberry Pi 4, but I keep getting the error:

Exception while writting to cloud InfluxDB: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f73bd2550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 113] No route to host